# Plotting K-means results in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, k-means

I have 3 sets of signals, each containing 4 distinct operational states, and I have to classify the states in each signal using K-means in Matlab. The classification is done after I have smoothened the original signal using a filter. My output should be a plot of the smoothened signal with each part of the signal in a different color to denote the different operational state.

I am very new to Matlab, and this is what I have for the classification part.

```
numClusters = 4;
idx_1 = kmeans([X_1 smoothY_1],numClusters,'Replicates', 5);
[numDataPoints,numDimensions] = size(smoothY_1);
Colors = hsv(numClusters);
for i = 1 : numDataPoints
    plot(X_1(i),smoothY_1(i),'.','Color',Colors(idx_1(i),:))
    hold on
end
```

I have a few questions.

1) It appears to me that the kmeans function in Matlab will return a set of arbitrary cluster index in every run. For example, running the code above on the same signal twice may give me the cluster index (for 10 data points) `[4 4 2 2 2 1 1 3 3 3]` and `[2 2 1 1 1 4 4 3 3 3]`, resulting in arbitrary colors denoting each state. Ideally, I would like the indices to be (somewhat) ordered and the colors to be the same for corresponding states, so that it makes sense to say "Red means Operational State 1, blue means State 2, etc". How can I synchronize this?

I have 2 pictures to illustrate this.
[image: Picture]

Set 1 and 2 are two of the datasets. Each stage of the signal is in a different color. I would like, for example, the first segment to be red, second in cyan, third in green, fourth in purple.

2) I can't seem to plot the graph using the specifier '-'. There is no output when I tried to do that, so I'm forced to use '.', which isn't what i want. How can I plot a continuous curve here?

3) Right now, I'm running K-means independently on all 3 sets of data, so there's no concept of training/test datasets. I would like to use one dataset for training and the other 2 for testing, but I don't know how to do that using K-means in Matlab. How can I do that?

**ETA:** I noticed that my smoothed plots are all about half the heights of my plots of the original data, e.g. the highest point in my original signal is y = 22, while the highest point in my smoothed signal is y = 11, although the shape remains the same. Is this correct?

**ETA2:** I realized that it seems as if what the K-means clustering did was simply divide the graph into numClusters segments (based on X_1 values) and that's it. I've tried with different values of numClusters and each gave me equally divided segments. Surely this can't be right? For instance, isn't it more likely that the long segment after the biggest spike belong to the same cluster, rather than 3 clusters? Should I be using K-means at all?

Answer (score 2):

**For the first question:**

You can reorder your vector with

```
[~,~,a] = unique(a,'stable');
```

**For the second question:**

You can find all the information about the LineSpec here:

[LineSpec](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#inputarg_LineSpec)

If you don't add a LineSpec the default option is a continuous line, as you want.

**For the third question:**

I don't think that you can train your kmean algorithm (due to the method) as it could be possible with an SVM, but i'm waiting for an expert opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

However, wouldn't the `unique` function remove duplicate points in my idx_1? How would this affect my plot since now the size of the idx_1 vector is smaller than my x,y vectors?

Also, I've tried 
`plot(X_1(i),smoothY_1(i),'Color',Colors(idx_1(i),:))` and `plot(X_1(i),smoothY_1(i))`, both of which returned no curve.

Comment: `a = unique(a)` remove duplicate points. But `[~,~,a] = unique(a,'stable')` only reorder your vector: `[2 2 3 3 3 1 1 1 1]` become `[1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3]`. Concerning the plot, your code is right so it should work !  But i suspect that your X_1 and smoothY_1 have more than 1 dimension.

Comment: You have certainly more than 1 parameter to compute the clusters. So try something like `plot(X_1(1,:),smoothY_1(1,:))` or `plot(X_1(:,1),smoothY_1(:,1))` to plot the first parameter.

Comment: Thanks, the unique function worked perfectly.
I still can't get the plot right, though. My X_1 and Y_1 arrays are both "1825x1 double". I tried `plot(X_1(1,:),smoothY_1(1,:))` and there was no plot, I tried `plot(X_1(:,1),smoothY_1(:,1))` and there was a continuous plot, but only in one color. And `plot(X_1(i,1),smoothY_1(i,1),'-','Color',Colors(idx_1_sorted(i),:))` still gave no plot. I think I have to include the LineSpec to have the different colors based on the cluster index.

Comment: `[~,~,a] = unique(a,'stable');
jetc = jet(length(unique(a)));
jeta = jetc(a,:);
scatter(X_1(:,1),smoothY_1(:,1),25,jeta,'filled');`